# Doctrine getRepository() is actively refused by SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am able to access the `database` though via `pdo` queries. Now I'm new to both of these things as I'm new to `php`, so I don't know which is preferred to use, but I assume an entity manager would be easier.
My goal is to have a simple `web` application that can show data from an `sql-server` `database`.

*System*

- `windows` 8
- `php` 7
- `sql-server` `pdo` 4
- `symfony` 3

Error message:

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: 
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

My code:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:MyObject');
```

*MyObject.php*

```
<?php
// src/MyBundle/Entity/MyObject.php

namespace MyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MyObject
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="MyObject")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\MyObjectRepository")
 */
class MyObject {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=4)
     */
    private $type;
}
```

*MyObjectRepository.php*

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: rsluimers
 * Date: 28-7-2017
 * Time: 10:55
 */

namespace MyBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class MyObjectRepository extends EntityRepository {

    public function create() {
        $entity = new MyObject();
        $entity->type('WM_B');
        $this->_em->persist($entity);
        $this->_em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure correctly you parameters.yml file?

Comment: `persist` and `flush` methods are not static in `EntityManager`. Also your code doesn't make sens in `MyObjectRepository extends MyObjectRepository`. And moreover your method `MyObject::getRepository` is not a good idea.

Comment: The most possibly cause is firewall.

Comment: @JakubMatczak Thanks. The repository and entity code are pieces I plucked from stackoverflow, although the second mistake was a renaming typo.

Comment: @rmsluimers can you post `doctrine.dbal` configuration from `config.yml`?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the parameters file if everything is correct there:

```
database_host: localhost
database_port: port
database_name: database
database_user: user
database_password: pass
```

Comment: I can access the database via raw PDO, so that's correct.